# sending email with java API

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

i want to make a simple program in java that send a email to original person and cc person but email are send only to cc person.
i am using coding stuff like as:

```
InternetAddress[] toMail = InternetAddress.parse(to,false);
InternetAddress[] ccMail = InternetAddress.parse(cc,false);
msg.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,toMail);
msg.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC,ccMail);
```

please help.

thanks

Comment: Do you get any error messages? It's a bit difficult right now to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Can you give us a little bit more information?  For example, can you specify the email addresses being used, maybe they are incorrectly formatted.

Comment: no, i am not getting any error. it only send the email to CC email ID.

Comment: email ID like as: abc@gmail.com

Comment: It seems your ccMail is replacing your toMail Object at addRecipients.

Comment: Did you try switching on [JavaMail debug](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#debug), at least for kicks?

Comment: i also got this error: javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Illegal address in string ``''   when i use this code: msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to,false));
  msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC,new InternetAddress(cc,false));

Comment: Thanks GustlyWind ccMail was replacing with toMail Object.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Error posted here there could be many possibilities where you are putting you email address as **Empty String** ("")

Please try to print the email address of **To, CC, and Sender** just to make sure if they are correct.